# Using custom libraries from top level in Scheme (Racket 6.3)

Tags: scheme, racket

Following the instructions in http://www.scheme.com/csug8/libraries.html, I could build a library `smcho.ss`.

```
(library (smcho simple (1))
    (export hello factorial)
    (import (rnrs (6)))

    (define (hello x)
      (+ x 10))

    (define (factorial n)
        (cond
            [(<= n 0) 1]
            [else (* n (factorial (- n 1)))]))
)
```

Then, install it with `plt-r6rs --install smcho.ss` (http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2009-September/035465.html).

However, when I tried to use it in top_level.ss,

```
(import (smcho simple) (rnrs (6)))    
(print (factorial 10))
```

I have error messages

```
scheme> plt-r6rs top_level.sc 
get-module-code: no such file: #<path:/Users/smcho/Desktop/scheme_lib/top_level.sc>
  context...:
```

What might be wrong? 
I checked that the `~/Library/Racket/6.3/collects` directory stores correctly compiled library, so the issue should not be from the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I should have used `(display (factorial 10))` not `print`. Furthermore, In DrRacket GUI, I needed to add `#lang r6rs` to run in it.

I'm not sure why `display` is OK when `print` or `pr` causes an issue.

Comment: Racket provides a `print` function, but R6RS does not. The R6RS standard only defines `display`.